# Как остановить объект на последней точке, чтобы анимация не начиналась сначала в TRHEE.js

Tags: javascript, анимация, three.js

Пытаюсь сделать, как вот [здесь](http://jsfiddle.net/SCXNQ/891/) , но нужно, чтобы куб останавливался на последней точке, а не начинал анимироваться сначала. Подскажите, как это сделать, пожалуйста!

`

```
var wd = window;

var ctnEl = document.getElementById('ctn');
var camera, scene, renderer;
var cubes = [], plane, marker, spline;


// ALLOCATE THESE OUTSIDE OF THE RENDER LOOP - CHANGED
var matrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
var up = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 1, 0 );
var axis = new THREE.Vector3( );
var pt, radians, axis, tangent;


var winDims = [ctnEl.offsetWidth, ctnEl.offsetHeight];
var winHalfW = winDims[0] / 2;

function init() {
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, winDims[0] / winDims[1], 1, 8000);
    
    camera.position.y = 350;
    camera.position.z = 300;
    camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(150, 150, 0));   
    scene.add(camera);
    
    for(var i = 0; i < 15; i++){
        //cubes.push(getCube());
    }
    
    var increment = (360 / cubes.length);
    for(var i = 0; i < cubes.length; i++){
        var angle = i * increment;
        var x = Math.cos(angle * (Math.PI / 180)) * 450;
        var y = Math.sin(angle * (Math.PI / 180)) * 450;
        cubes[i].position.x = x;
        cubes[i].position.z = y;
 
        scene.add(cubes[i]);
    }
    
    marker = getCube();
    scene.add(marker);
    
    // plane
    plane = new THREE.Mesh(
        new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1500, 1500),
        new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( {color: 0xff0000} )
    );
    scene.add(plane);

    spline = new THREE.SplineCurve3([
       new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0),
       new THREE.Vector3(0, 200, 0),
       new THREE.Vector3(150, 150, 0),
       new THREE.Vector3(150, 50, 0),
       new THREE.Vector3(250, 150, 0),
       new THREE.Vector3(250, 300, 0)
    ]);
    
    var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
        color: 0xff00f0,
    });
    
    var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
    for(var i = 0; i < spline.getPoints(100).length; i++){
        geometry.vertices.push(spline.getPoints(100)[i]);  
    }
    
    var line = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
    scene.add(line);
    

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    
    renderer.setSize(winDims[0], winDims[1]);
    ctnEl.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
}

function getCube(){
    // cube mats and cube
    var mats = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i ++) {
        mats.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:Math.random()*0xffffff}));
    }
    
    var cube = new THREE.Mesh(
        new THREE.CubeGeometry(100, 100, 100, 1, 1, 1),
        new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( mats )
    );
   
    return cube
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    
    render();
}
    
var t = 0;
function render() {
    
    // set the marker position
    pt = spline.getPoint( t );
    marker.position.set( pt.x, pt.y, pt.z );
    
    // get the tangent to the curve
    tangent = spline.getTangent( t ).normalize();
    
    // calculate the axis to rotate around
    axis.crossVectors( up, tangent ).normalize();
    
    // calcluate the angle between the up vector and the tangent
    radians = Math.acos( up.dot( tangent ) );
        
    // set the quaternion
    marker.quaternion.setFromAxisAngle( axis, radians );
        
    t = (t >= 1) ? 0 : t += 0.002;

    renderer.render(scene, camera); 
}

init();
animate();
```

`

Comment: В строке `t = (t >= 1) ? 0 : t += 0.002;`, можно например `0` заменить на `t`. [Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/ve08sxk7/)

Comment: Или `t+=0.002; t = THREE.MathUtils.clamp(t, 0,1);`, чтобы `t` было всегда в пределах от 0 до 1. То есть, значение `t` не превысит 1. Это вместо все той же строки `t = (t >= 1) ? 0 : t += 0.002;`.

Comment: Ну, или `t = (t >= 1) ? 1 : t += 0.002;`